# Clang fatal error for -ast-print command

Tags: c, llvm

I just started using llvm and trying to print basic commands of llvm, when i tried to execute 
`clang -cc1 ~/hello.c -ast-print`
getting  following error

fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found

```
#include<stdio.h>
              ^
int main()
{
    printf("hi\n");
    return 0;
}
```

1 error generated.

so please help me out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With `-cc1` you invoke the *frontend*, not the gcc-compatible compiler driver. The latter knows how to find standard header includes, the former doesn't.

If you want to use `-cc1` with files including from standard libraries, then either supply all relevant paths with `-I`, or just run it on preprocessed files.